# Iterate over all panels in screen?

Tags: python, scripting, interface, operator, panel

I have a timer that is running in the background.

I'm trying to identify the running operator by its panel, so when that operator's panel goes away, I execute some code.

I thought about iterating all the panels in the screen, and checking for the one with my operator, so I can check when its panel goes away.

Edit: I mean to check that kind of panels that appears when an operator is running:
[image]

Is that possible?

PS: I know there is `bpy.context.active_operator`, but this stores the last one until a new one is executed (so it is stills storing the operator even after its panel is hidden)

Thank you so much for the help.